# How do I make objects randomly spawn within a radius in a 3D unity game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to make some sort of radius or area for it first, probably using coordinates. Then at random times (this will be a random.range variable), there will be a prefab spawn in. There are many solutions but they do not work for me or fit in with what I want.

I tried multiple different ways as I said, and they didnt work
The image was a quick sketch.

Thank you.

Comment: What did you try, why did the attempts fail, and how did they not work for you or fit in with what you want?

Answer (score 0):

This code will generate a random position within a radius:

```
private Vector3 GetRandomPositionInRadius(float radius)
{
    // get quaternion of random rotation in all 3 axes
    Quaternion quat = Quaternion.Euler(Random.Range(0.0f, 360.0f), Random.Range(0.0f, 360.0f), Random.Range(0.0f, 360.0f));

    // get forward vector
    Vector3 forward = quat * Vector3.forward;

    // get random distance from center, and move that way to find position
    Vector3 position = forward * Random.Range(0.0f, radius);

    return position;
}
```

Short explanation: In this function, it finds a random rotation using a Quaternion. The quaternion does all of the hard math, we just give it random X, Y and Z rotations from 0 to 360 degrees. Then we find the way the quaternion is facing, and move out from the center, a random amount from 0 to radius, giving a random local position/offset from the center.

Comment: Depending on the implementation he might not need a sphere of possible positions but a circle. This can be achieved by setting the `Y` value of the `Quaternion` to 0 instead of a random value.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for your case

```
public Vector3 GetRandomPosInRadius(Vector3 centerPoint, float radius)
{
    return centerPoint + (UnityEngine.Random.insideUnitSphere * radius);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
public class ObjectSpawn : MonoBehaviour
{
  [SerializeField] private GameObject objectToSpawn;
  private float radius = 5; // change this
  private float minTime = 1, maxTime = 10; //change this

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(Spawner()); 
}

IEnumerator Spawner()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(minTime, maxTime));
    Vector3 randPos = Random.insideUnitSphere * radius;
    Instantiate(objectToSpawn, transform.position + randPos, Quaternion.identity);
    StartCoroutine(Spawner());
}
```

}